# How to read CSV with \", sequence inside quoted character value in R?

Tags: r, csv, fread, read.csv, readr

Here is a CSV file with two character columns:

```
"key","value"
"a","\","
```

All character values are quoted by double quotes. And there is a sequence `\",` inside one of the values (escaped quote plus delimiter). I cannot correctly read this file neither by read.csv, nor by read_csv from readr, nor by fread from data.table.

Comment: Interestingly, if \" and , are separated by space than both read_csv and fread reads the file correctly. But read.csv still fails. The problem is I cannot alter content of the file and must read it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readr`'s `read_delim`, which is more general than `read_csv`:

```
library(readr)

read_delim('yourfile.csv', 
           delim = ",", 
           escape_double = FALSE, 
           escape_backslash = TRUE)
```