# Replacing specific special-character combination \" in csv using python or R

Tags: python, r, csv, replace, special-characters

I have a large batch of CSVs containing numeric and string columns, in which there will occasionally appear the combination of two special characters `\"`. This combination will occasionally appear at the end of a string, such as `"string\""`, and the adjacent double quotes can confuse some software when attempting to import. I want to strip all CSVs of `\"` (but obviously not of individual `"` or `\` characters) and then save/replace the CSVs. How can I do it? Python or R preferred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983633/how-to-read-csv-with-sequence-inside-quoted-character-value-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using input file

slash_quote.csv:

```
"a","string\"","b"
```

with code:

```
files = ("slash_quote.csv",)

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        with open(filename+"_new", "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(f.read().replace(r'\"', ''))
            # if replacement is desired include
            os.rename(f"{filename}_new", filename)
```

output file:

```
"a","string","b"
```